# Problem with Nplot Reference in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am currently developing a C# application where I am using NPlot dll for creating graphs in my software.

I am having a really weird problem when referencing the DLL. I have downloaded Nplot 0.9.10.0 zip file and copied the Nplot.dll from the zip file/bin/net/2.0/release to my project directory.

I then go into Visual Studio 2010 and right click on references and browse to the DLL. VS2010 adds the reference find and I can put in the top of my class `using NPlot;`

Which it accepts fine. I enter all the code required and when hovering the mouse over the code it says that its using the reference from NPlot and no errors are displayed when I save the file.

When I then build the project and try to run it then says Type or Namespace NPlot doesn't could not be found. And it says that using NPlot can't be found even though it is still shown in the references on VS2010.

What is wrong with this, how can it be fine and accept the reference until I build it and it then says the reference doesn't exist.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**EDIT:** Just noticed after I posted this that when the reference is added to VS2010 a warning is displayed saying

> 'Could not resolve this reference.
>   Could not locate the assembly "NPlot".
>   Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because you created a .Net 4.0 Client Project in VS2010, while the NPlot library is a .Net 2.0 application.

In VS2010 goto your project settings and change the .Net framework to be .Net 4.0 (Not the Client Profile) and recompile and you should be set.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Was using .Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile so changed to .Net Framework 3.5 and it now works fine. Thanks again